# Neo4j HTTP error

Tags: rest, neo4j

So, I thought that I configured everything correctly by following the installation and setup instructions in the neo4j documentation, but the REST API is not working.

http:7474/localhost works perfectly and detects nodes, but

```
curl http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0<html>
```

gets

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /db/data/node/0. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                

</body>
```

The older documentation had something about installing the neo4j-rest separately, but this is not in the current documentation. Thoughts?

Comment: which version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: What is it you say works perfectly?

Comment: Did you delete node 0 previously?

Comment: Version is 1.8.2 community. Works perfectly in the sense that cypher queries return everything as they're supposed to, and the web admin UI works. I don't *think* that I deleted node 0, and searching for it in the web interface returns data.